# How do I integrate $\frac{\sin x}{ \cos x+\cos 2x} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to evaluate : 
$$ I=\int \dfrac {\sin x }{ \cos x+\cos 2x}\, dx$$

I tried to write $\cos 2x$ as $\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ then use $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ but I couldn't do any substitution, how can I integrate this.

Comment: It is very easy with the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: is this what you mean ?

Comment: More explicitly, let $t=\tan(x/2)$ then $$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\cos(2x)}\,\mathrm dx=\int \frac{2t}{1-3t^2}\,\mathrm dt=-\frac13 \ln(1-3t^2)$$

Comment: @LostInSpace yes thank you

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch thank you so much

Comment: Or you could use $c=\cos x$ so $\cos 2x=2c^2-1$.

Comment: You could also rewrite $\cos(2x) = 2 \cos^2 x - 1$ instead and then do a substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\int\frac{\sin x\mathrm dx}{\cos x+\cos 2x}=\int\frac{\sin x\mathrm dx}{2\cos^2x+\cos x-1}=\int\frac{\sin x\mathrm dx}{(2\cos x-1)(\cos x+1)}$$

Set $u=\cos x$, $ \mathrm du =-\sin x\mathrm dx$. Can you proceed?

Comment: (+1) All to easy and circumvent the tangent half-angle substitution, as comments suggested using.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

*Bioche's rules* suggest the substitution $u=\cos x$, $\mathrm du=-\sin x\,\mathrm dx$ . You obtain, using the duplication formula for $\cos 2x$,
$$ I=\int \frac {\sin x }{\cos x+\cos 2x}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{-\mathrm d u}{u+2u^2-1}=\int\frac{\mathrm d u}{(1+u)(1-2u)}.$$
There remains to decompose this fraction into simple fractions, integrate and revert to the initial variable.